# Python 3.0 Calling a value from a class function to print

Tags: python

Trying to call the total hours from the class/function down to the instance of the class I created below. (hope i worded that correctly)

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self):
    self.wage = 0
    self.hours = 0
    if self.hours > 40:
      self.ot = self.hours - 40                 #overtime hours
      self.earned_ot = self.wage * 1.5          #overtime wage rate
      self.ot_total = self.ot * self.earned_ot  #pay for overtime hours
      self.pay = self.wage * 40                 #standard hour wage
      self.total = self.pay + self.ot_total     #standard wage + ot hour wage
    else:
      self.total = self.wage * self.hours

alice = Employee()
alice.wage = 20
alice.hours = 40
#alice.total = 

bob = Employee()
bob.wage = 15
bob.hours = 50
#bob.total = 

print("Alice: \n Net pay: ${} \nBob: \n Net pay: ${}" .format(alice.total, 
bob.total))
```

Issue I'm having seems simple enough but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I commented out the alice.total and bob.total for now, but those are what I need to get the print to work correctly.

I feel like i'm forgetting something simple, but browsing back through my notes/texts I can't figure it out. Does anyone who sees the issue that I'm having, have a link to something that might explain this? I'm not looking for an outright answer, just a point in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Code in `__init__` runs at the time you are creating the instance, i.e. when you do `Employee()`. At that time, neither `wage` nor `hours` have a value, so the calculation of `total` uses the default values. You will need to have some trigger (e.g. a method) to actually calculate `total` **after** you have set `wage` and `hours`. Or pass those values to `__init__` directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [the @property decorator](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php):

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self):
    self.wage = 0
    self.hours = 0

  @property
  def total(self):
    if self.hours > 40:
      ot = self.hours - 40                 #overtime hours
      earned_ot = self.wage * 1.5          #overtime wage rate
      ot_total = ot * earned_ot  #pay for overtime hours
      pay = self.wage * 40                 #standard hour wage
      return pay + ot_total     #standard wage + ot hour wage
    else:
      return self.wage * self.hours
```

Comment: Thanks, the @property did the trick. Thanks for the link/info!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code would benefit from changing the constructor to:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, wage=0, hours=0):
        self.wage = wage
        self.hours = hours
```

and placing the rest of the code in a method:

```
class Employee:
    ....

    def get_total(self):
        total = ... # calculate from self.wage and self.hours
        return total

alice = Employee(wage=20, hours=40)
print(alice.get_total())
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass `wage` and `hours` to the constructor ? `alice = Employee(20, 40)`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers OP might have to compute the total multiple times

Comment: @RottenCandy yes possibly, and then ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers If he passes the values to the constructor as you suggest. Then the object receives the values only at initialization. It might not be possible to compute the `total` again for a different set of values without using methods for the specific purpose.

Comment: @RottenCandy passing wage and hours to the constructor does not  mean the total must be computed at this point, and setting those attributes afterwards implies you do need a method to recompute the total anyway. FWIW the whole design is already wrong - in a real program this would be the responsibility of another object - but this  is obviously a toy program.

Answer (score 0):

You could either change your constructor

```
class Employee:
    def init(self, wage=0, hours=0):
    self.wage = wage
    self.hours = hours
```

And instantiate your employee

```
alice = Employee(20, 40)
```

The rest of your code can be left unchanged.
However I'll advise to use something like properties so you can change wage/hours without creating a new `Employee` and still get a accurate value

```
class Employee:
     def init(self):
         self._wage = 0
         self._hours = 0

     @property
     def wage(self):
         return self._wage

     @wage.setter
     def wage(self, value):
         self._wage = value

     @property
     def hours(self):
         return self._hours

     @hours.setter
     def hours(self, value):
         self._hours = value

     @property
     def total(self):
         if self.hours > 40:
             self.ot = self.hours - 40                 #overtime hours
             self.earned_ot = self.wage * 1.5          #overtime wage rate
             self.ot_total = self.ot * self.earned_ot  #pay for overtime hours
             self.pay = self.wage * 40                 #standard hour wage
             return self.pay + self.ot_total     #standard wage + ot hour wage
         else:
             return self.wage * self.hours
```

Your code to instantiate and get/set wage/hours on an `Employee` can stay the same
More details on property : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

**Edit:** Modified my answer based on comments made

Comment: Thanks, this worked well also. Thank you for the link/info!

Comment: Normally I'd use `@property` for computed properties like `self.total`, your example shows a different approach - update computed properties whenever their dependency changes. But in this case I'd expect that both the `wage` and `hours` setters re-calculate `self.total`.

Comment: using properties is a good idea but you're doing it wrong - the right way is of coutse to make total a property (you can eventually make it a cached property in which case wage and hour should be properties too but just invalidatong the cache on set. Also you want the implementation attributes to be protected not private (usual beginner error) and your hours  setter should be named hours not wage.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've edited my answer based on yours and Kos's comment. But why should the attributes be protected instead of private ? Is it just a python convention ? thanks

Comment: @olricson: private variables (well, there's no real privacy in Python - only naming conventions, plus name mangling for `__names`) will not be accessible from subclasses (unless you use the mangled names, which would be kind of dumb).  Since Python  has no real privacy whatsoever _and_ a good support for computed attributes, there real use cases for `__private` attributes are very very few. As an example, there might be a couple or so such names in the whole Django code base for example, and actually not in the most critical parts of the framework.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm aware that private is really just a naming convention (`__private` == `_classname__private`) but did not know the protected over private convention. Thanks for the django example, for sure these guys know own to write python code :)